# idea for array matching

Tags: php, arrays, session, foreach

I have a problem and if someone can give me an answer i would be very happy and thsnkful. So, I have this array, that is shown from this code:

```
print_r($this->session->userdata('cart'));
```

Result:

> `Array ( [product_name] => Array ( [0] => Optoma ML1000 [1] => Smart Board i885 [2] => Optoma W316 ) [product_price] => Array ( [0] => 12000 [1] => 3000 [2] => 652 ) [product_quantity] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 ) [total] => 15652 )`

Can someone give me an idea how to match all of them and to make a foreach to display them.
Example:

```
'product_name' = Optoma ML1000; 'product_price' = 12000; 'product_quantity' = 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by "match all of them"

Comment: you've already tagged your question with the answer: foreach.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to create an array where you have to store the first element value of each array with the key of the array :

```
$Result = [];
foreach($this->session->userdata('cart') as $key => $value)
   $Result[$key] = $value[0];
```

Now all the data you need is in `$Result`

```
$Result['product_name']; // contains the value "Optoma ML1000"
$Result['product_price']; // contains the value 12000
$Result['product_quantity']; // contains the value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = Array ( 
    "product_name" => Array ("Optoma ML1000",  "Smart Board i885", "Optoma W316"), 
    "product_price" => Array ( 12000,3000,652 ),
    "product_quantity" => Array ( 1,1,1 ),
    "total" => 15652 );

$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($a ['product_name']));
$iterator->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($a ['product_price']));
$iterator->attachIterator (new ArrayIterator ($a ['product_quantity']));

foreach ($iterator as $value)
{
    var_dump ($value);
    // or what have you
}
```

The output is:

```
array (
  0 => 'Optoma ML1000',
  1 => 12000,
  2 => 1,
)array (
  0 => 'Smart Board i885',
  1 => 3000,
  2 => 1,
)array (
  0 => 'Optoma W316',
  1 => 652,
  2 => 1,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is setup a little strange, but this should work...

```
$items = print_r($this->session->userdata('cart'));
for ($i=0; $i < count($items['product_name']); $i++) { 
    echo $items['product_name'][$i];
    echo $items['product_price'][$i];
    echo $items['product_quantity'][$i];
}
```

Ideally, it should be setup like so...

```
array(
    array(
        'product_name' => 'Optoma ML1000',
        'product_price' => 12000,
        'product_quantity' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'product_name' => 'Smart Board i885',
        'product_price' => 3000,
        'product_quantity' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'product_name' => 'Optoma W316',
        'product_price' => 652,
        'product_quantity' => 1
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each of the three inner arrays simultaneously by doing this:

```
$cart = $this->session->userdata('cart');
foreach(array_map(null, $cart['product_name'],
                        $cart['product_price'],
                        $cart['product_quantity']) as $x) {

  print_r(sprintf("product_name: %s, product_price: %s, product_quantity: %s\n", $x[0], $x[1], $x[2]));
}
```